# How to write logging for jaxb-impl

Tags: java, logging, jaxb

I am required to write logs for jaxb-impl.jar. When I searched online (https://java.net/projects/jaxb/lists/users/archive/2007-01/message/5), I found that we need to enable logs in JDK i.e logging.properties (C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WMBT700\jdk\jre\lib). Based on my further search I found that we need to enable logs and trace in Java control panel, I even specified the jre inside the control panel.

Now to see the logs in the file, I have configured the file handler in logging.properties

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myfile.log
```

Handler used is specified as file handler

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler
```

and the process is specified as

```
com.sun.xml.bind = FINEST
```

I am still not getting the logs.

**I checked the class files using decompiler. To my surprise I found no code as java.util.log..., Is that the reason why logs are not getting generated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=myfile
```

Here, myfile should be custom configuration file. 
So try by either specifying your own configuration file or without specifying this system property in case if you have modified logging.properties

Also level could be changed to,

```
.level = ALL (default is INFO).
```

This may not be an answer but as i am new and i do not have that much reputation to comment so added it as answer if it may help :)

Comment: Thanks for correcting one mistake, and I am upvoting for that.